# it is possible to read delegated email inbox from Google Apps Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, gmail-api

I allready have acccess (and also I am the administrator) of a delegated Inbox. I wanna run a Google Apps Script to read email from the delegated Inbox.

Is that possible?

It works with my main account, but not with the delegated one.
I get a 403 => Delegation denied for xxxx@gmail.com

Comment: have you tried?  If you can authenticate the script then it should be possible.

Comment: Yes I Did. I can read mails from my main Inbox but not from the delegated one, I get an 403 => Delegation denied

Comment: Are you trying to use the Gmail Service or the Gmail API?

Comment: Yes I do. I tried with Gmail.Users.Messages.list('xxxx@gmail.com')

Comment: Any answer on this?  Would love to be able to read from my delegated account.  Should not be a permission problem since I can select the account in Gmail read/write that way.

Comment: Sorry Scott, 3 months later I had to do a workaround, is not possible to read delegated accounts from GAS by the moment.